# UITableViewCell awakeFromNib wrong frame size

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, resize, autolayout

I have a UITableViewCell with constraints so that the cells layout correctly on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.

The cell contents correctly resize correctly. However, I need to draw a sublayer gradient over one of the views inside. In order to do so, I'm using awakeFromNib to draw the sublayer.

AwakeFromNib is giving the size of the frame prior to it autoresizing and therefore the gradient subview isn't the right size.

If I use layoutSubviews, the first time it's called, the size is also wrong and the cell needs to be scrolled before it has the right size; so that method also isn't working

What method should I be using to get the right frame size in order to draw correctly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This code worked for me, is written in **Swift**.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var gradientView: UIView!

    private let gl = CAGradientLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // set gradient
        let colors: [AnyObject] = [
            UIColor.clearColor().CGColor,
            UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.8).CGColor
        ]
        gl.colors = colors
        gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gl, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // update gradient
        gl.frame = gradientView.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: layoutSubview() is called a lot of times, it is not good practice to add code inside it. It reduces performance. Better the solution of overriding drawRect method

Answer (score 23):

during awakeFromNib the frame layouts do not appear. On your custom Cell you can either do this

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    // Enter Custom Code
}
```

Or you can override applyLayoutAttributes method like this

```
-(void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    [super applyLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
    // Enter custom Code here

}
```

applyLayoutAttributes is called before drawRect method but still has the size parameteres of rect.

Comment: applyLayoutAttributes appears to only work for collectionCells. For my UITableViewCell I used your drawRect: answer - thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, but overriding drawRect usually reduces performance right ?

Answer (score 8):

@angshuk answer is perfect where if anyone wants to modify UI inside `UITableViewCell`. Like in my case I was trying to add a different layer on runtime to an `UIView`, placed inside `UITableViewCell` using storyboard/autolayout. Tried the same thing inside `awakeFromNib()` & `layoutSubviews()` also. Nothing worked.

Here is the same code using Swift. By the way I am using Xcode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.2.

```
import UIKit

class InviteMainCellClass: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var shareCodeLblSuperView: UIView!  //Custom view added using IB/Autolayout

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //shareCodeLblSuperView.addDashedBorderToView(self.shareCodeLblSuperView, viewBorderColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), borderWidth: 1.0) //Not worked
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    shareCodeLblSuperView.addDashedBorderToView(self.shareCodeLblSuperView, viewBorderColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), borderWidth: 1.0) //Worked
}



override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //shareCodeLblSuperView.addDashedBorderToView(self.shareCodeLblSuperView, viewBorderColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), borderWidth: 1.0)//Not worked
}
```

Hope this helped. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, but overriding drawRect usually reduces performance right ?

Comment: It worked for me, finally I found an answer that my cell got its correct frame. Thanks!